# Partial Mash Extract twang

Tags: off-flavor, partial-mash

The off flavor i am tasting is sweet, and actually tastes malty/caramel.  It's supposed to be an IPA but this sweet flavor is disconnected form the hops.  Will leaving it in the bottle longer help this out?  I did use 9lbs of LME for this recipe and about 3 oz of hops and a few oz of grain.  The sweetness really does bother me.

Comment: Oh and it sat in the primary for 1 week and the secondary for 2 before being bottled.

Comment: There is a chance that if you had left it i primary for all 3 weeks the flavor may not have happened or may have been at a reduced level.  IF you somehow managed to oxidize it when you moved to secondary it would exacerbate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Extract twang is not an extract issue at all.  It is a fermentation issue derived from poor yeast health, under pitching, temperature fluctuations or any other phenomena that stresses yeast out.

If the beer was only in primary for one week with poorly fermenting yeast that could be the source of your problem.  Next time go with two weeks primary as a minimum, at the least.

In my experience, it will not really go away in the bottle only get more pronounced as the beer ages/oxidizes slightly.

Comment: I think I'd modify your statement to say "it could be a fermentation issue".  I think there are other possible causes, too.

Comment: Thanks for the help fellas, I will be fermenting in  my primary for a minumum of 2 weeks from now on.  As well as possibly switching to DME

Comment: Brewchez : why do you say this isn't an extract issue?

Answer (score 0):

Old extract has been found to produce that kind of off flavor.  For that reason, either make sure the LME you use is fresh or use DME instead.  It has much less chance of being stale and oxidized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I agree that this isn't an extract issue (though you certainly could have interrupted fermentation as well).  Depending on the malter's process and the darkness of the LME you used, you may be tasting excess melanoidins produced by the malter or by your concentrated partial boil.  I think if you boil too long, you might also experience this flavor.

This brief article discusses Browning reactions briefly.  Start there http://morebeer.com/articles/kettle_reactions

Oxidation could certainly contribute as well.

Comment: I'm boiling for right around 60 minutes, adding whatever hops during that time